# Adding Fields of growing fields Unix

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a grade book file that looks like

`StudentID:LastName:FirstName:hw01:quiz01:exam01:proj01:quiz02:
 0123:Smith:Jon:100:80:80:100:90:
 0987:Williams:Pat:20:30:35:46:50:
 0654:Bar:Foo:100:100:100:100:100:`

I need to add all the hws/quizes/exams/projects for each student and append the total to the end of the corresponding line

An example output file could be

`StudentID:LastName:FirstName:hw01:quiz01:exam01:proj01:quiz02:hT:qT:eT:pT
 0123:Smith:Jon:100:80:80:100:90:100:170:80:100:
 0987:Williams:Pat:20:30:35:46:50:20:80:35:46:
 0654:Bar:Foo:100:100:100:100:100:100:200:100:100:`

The output file doesn't have to be the same file, but keep in mind that the order of the grades in the header line (1st line) could be anything. So the order of the assignments could be in any order.

I'm assuming I must use grep to search the file for all fields containing "hw"/"quiz"/"exam"/"proj" and get the corresponding field. Then go through each line and add the totals for hw/quiz/exam/proj individually.

Maybe it's easier with awk?

Comment: Awk is probably the appropriate tool for the job. Perl or Python (or …) could do it too, but it is not something for `grep` or `sed`.

Comment: Does it need to be `hwT` or would `hT` be consistent with the other totals?

Comment: It does't matter what the final grade fields would be. It could be hT, i'll edit it. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: What have you tried so far? As Johnathan points out, this could be solved pretty easily with something like the `csv` module in Python or the `pandas` package, but probably not a job for a shell script (not saying it can't be done, just that it won't be trivial).

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I'm not near the script atm and I have little experience with awk. I know it could be easily done with python, but I would like to do it with Unix.

Comment: @EdMorton: The extra column headings are the first letter of the corresponding columns (`e` for 'exam', `p` for 'project', `h` for 'homework', `q` for 'quiz') plus `T` for total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=":" }
NR==1 {
    for (i=4;i<NF;i++) {
        name = substr($i,1,1) "T"
        nr2name[i] = name
        if (!seen[name]++) {
            names[++numNames] = name
        }
    }

    printf "%s", $0
    for (nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", names[nameNr], OFS
    }
    print ""
    next
}
{
    delete tot
    for (i=4;i<NF;i++) {
        name = nr2name[i]
        tot[name] += $i
    }

    printf "%s", $0
    for (nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", tot[names[nameNr]], OFS
    }
    print ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
StudentID:LastName:FirstName:hw01:quiz01:exam01:proj01:quiz02:hT:qT:eT:pT:
0123:Smith:Jon:100:80:80:100:90:100:170:80:100:
0987:Williams:Pat:20:30:35:46:50:20:80:35:46:
0654:Bar:Foo:100:100:100:100:100:100:200:100:100:
```

Comment: This answer was the one that worked for me, In every case. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job; it is intricate, though:

#### `script.awk`

```
BEGIN   { FS = ":"; OFS = FS }
NR == 1 {
            for (i = 4; i < NF; i++)
            {
                c = substr($i, 1, 1)
                if (!(c in columns)) order[n++] = c
                columns[c]++
                letter[i] = c
            }
            nf = NF
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                $(i+nf) = order[i] "T"
            print $0 OFS
            next
        }
        {
            for (c in columns) total[c] = 0
            for (i = 4; i < NF; i++)
            {
                c = letter[i]
                total[c] += $i
            }
            nf = NF
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                c = order[i]
                $(i+nf) = total[c]
            }
            print $0 OFS
        }
```

Explanation:

`BEGIN`:

- Set the input and output field separators.

`NR == 1`:

- Loop over the fields after the student ID and name fields.
- Extract the first letter.
- If the letter has not been seen before, note it in the `order` and increment the number of totals (`n`).
- Increment the number of times the letter has been seen.
- Record which letter goes with the current column.
- Add the new columns after the existing columns in sequence.
- Print the line plus a trailing output field separator (aka OFS or `:`).
- Note that $NF is empty because of the trailing `:` in the data, hence (unusually for `awk` scripts), `i < NF` rather than `i <= NF`.

Each other line:

- Reset the totals for each letter.
- For each of the scoring fields, find the letter that the column belongs to (`letter[i]`).
- Add the column to the total for the letter.
- For each of the extra fields in order, set the value of the appropriate extra field to the total for that letter.
- Print the record plus an extra colon (aka OFS).

#### `data`

```
StudentID:LastName:FirstName:hw01:quiz01:exam01:proj01:quiz02:
0123:Smith:Jon:100:80:80:100:90:
0987:Williams:Pat:20:30:35:46:50:
0654:Bar:Foo:100:100:100:100:100:
```

#### Sample output

```
$ awk -f script.awk data

StudentID:LastName:FirstName:hw01:quiz01:exam01:proj01:quiz02:hT:qT:eT:pT:
0123:Smith:Jon:100:80:80:100:90:100:170:80:100:
0987:Williams:Pat:20:30:35:46:50:20:80:35:46:
0654:Bar:Foo:100:100:100:100:100:100:200:100:100:
$
```

The only difference between this and the sample output in the question is a trailing colon on the title line, for consistency with the data lines (and input).

Comment: By convention and as implemented by all awk functions awk arrays with numeric indices start at 1, not 0, so you should really use `if (!(c in columns)) order[++n] = c ... for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)` instead of `if (!(c in columns)) order[n++] = c ... for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`. Having some arrays start at 1 (e.g. `$1..$NF`) and others at 0 can get confusing and easy to trip over.

Comment: Every answer here is awesome. I fully understand your explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with few adaptation
 - Order of Total is not the same (dynamic) 
 - Name of total is using full radical names without the last 2 digit
 - Use a parameter to define first field with data to count (4th here with `-v 'St=4'`)

```
awk -v 'St=4' '
   BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}
   NR==1 {
      printf "%s",$0
      for(i=St;i<=(nf=NF-1);i++){
         tn=$i;sub(/..$/,"T",tn)
         T[tn]=0;TN[i]=tn
         }
      Sep=""
      for(t in T){
          printf "%s%s",Sep,t;Sep=OFS
          }
      print Sep
      next
      }
   {
      for(i=St;i<=nf;i++){
         T[TN[i]]+=$i
         }
      for(i=1;i<=nf;i++)printf "%s%s",$i,OFS
      Sep=""
      for(t in T){
         printf "%s%s",Sep,T[t]
         T[t]=0;Sep=OFS
         }
      print Sep
   }' YourFile

StudentID:LastName:FirstName:hw01:quiz01:exam01:proj01:quiz02:examT:quizT:hwT:projT:
0123:Smith:Jon:100:80:80:100:90:80:170:100:100:
0987:Williams:Pat:20:30:35:46:50:35:80:20:46:
0654:Bar:Foo:100:100:100:100:100:100:200:100:100:
```